# How do you go back to the previous directory in Ranger?

Tags: cd-command, ranger

In Ranger you can go to a directory with <kbd>g</kbd>. When you type <kbd>g</kbd> it gives you a list of places you can very easily go. For example <kbd>g</kbd>, and then <kbd>p</kbd> takes me to `/tmp`. How do I get back to the directory I was in? What's the ranger equiv of `cd -`?

When I type <kbd>g</kbd> I do not see the option to `cd` back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From any directory,

- <kbd>H</kbd> goes backwards (where you were)
- <kbd>L</kbd> goes forwards.

Answer (score 1):

use <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> to go back to the dir you were in ie double tap single quote, ie equivalent to `cd -` (it's very handy)